# Titanium / How to temporarily store a photo to use in a later function

Tags: ios, image, camera, titanium, appcelerator

Titanium / for an iOS App:

How can I manage to take a photo, and then use this one later in a new function to for example show the photo, and put a slightly larger duplicate of it with a transparency on top of itself?

Comment: You want to save the photo first or you want the later function help?

Comment: Want to store it later, with the other ones on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note that I tried to edit the answer from Mitul Bhalia with the following, but the edit got knocked back. So here's how you do it:*

After taking the image, you can store it as a variable in the global object, `Alloy.Globals`. You can then access this else where or later on in your app.

For example:

```
takePhotoButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    Titanium.Media.showCamera({
    success:function(event) {
        if(event.mediaType === Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {

            // Store the file in a variable 
            var image = event.media;

            // Store the image in the global object
            Alloy.Globals.temporaryImage = image;

        } else {
        alert("got the wrong type back ="+event.mediaType);
    }
    },
    ...
```

And somewhere else in your app, after the image has been stored, for example:

```
var anImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({ image: Alloy.Globals.temporaryImage })
```

Also note that extensive use of the global object can cause memory issues, so try not to overdo it.

Comment: Boom! Thanks a lot, you two!! Works smoothly like a mango lassi running down your throat! Now I also do not have that huge delay that the storing of the image caused.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save photo then you can use Alloy.Globals to save data globally so you can use it later.

Alloy.Globals.photo = blob object;

Comment: thanks a lot for the info. think i wanted to move on too fast. am currently sitting down and learning some more about the basics :)

Comment: ehy, thansk for asking... no. actually I got back to learn some more about titanium. would consider myself as beginner. so i do not really yet know what a blob is.

Comment: have found a different way to solve my problem, though i do not know if it is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am currently solving my problem:

```
takePhotoButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    Titanium.Media.showCamera({
    success:function(event) {
        if(event.mediaType === Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {

            // Store the file in a variable 
            var image = event.media;
            var filename = 'myPhoto.jpg';
            takenPhoto = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, filename);
            takenPhoto.write(image);

        } else {
        alert("got the wrong type back ="+event.mediaType);
    }
    },
    ...
```

and then later I can use takenPhoto to show the picture I have taken with the camera.
But I do not really know if this is the best way and if it is even correct, as I do not use 'var' to initiate takenPhoto. But if I use 'var' I cannot use takenPhoto outside of the function.

Comment: so this is how I currently temporarily store the taken photo to use it later. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This isn't temporary as it saves the image into the app file system, so it will stay there permanently unless it is delete or the app is deleted from the users device.

Comment: day-um... this actually makes sense. so how can i store the image temporarily, like in a variable?

Comment: You should be able to store the image in the global object like as mentioned in Mitul Bhalia's answer. I'll edit it to provide an example